# Is there a portable or travel wireless router that supports 5GHz 802.11ac that can be powered via USB?

Tags: usb, router

Is there a portable or travel wireless router that supports 5GHz 802.11ac? I'm looking to install one in my car with through its integrated USB port, or via 12v DC adapter?

Comment: What research have you done on your own?

Comment: I've been looking around on Amazon and eBay, but all appear to max out with 2.4GHz and 802.11n capabilities.

Comment: Ok, so you have looked around.  Reason I ask, is some people don't do any at all.  I'll look around.  This sounds like one of those "this should exist" products, that for some reason may not exist lol.

Comment: Right. This should exist, considering the technology has been available for a while now. The 2.4GHz frequency is too saturated, and I'm trying to avoid a power inverter just to plug in a big and clunky 5GHz one.

Comment: And.....I was just going to suggest the inverter route.  I cannot find a portable 5G either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[D-Link AC-750 Portable](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wi-fi-ac750-portable-router-and-charger-3/)

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HGLOQ24) $98.09

- IEEE802.11ac/n/a/g/b
- Allows simultaneous 2.4G and 5G Networks
- USB 5V Charging

Additionaly serves as an additional battery and power source for other devices.

From reading the reviews it seems to be able to run on its own power for at least 4 Hours

Answer (score 0):

[Buffalo Router Specs](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/airstation-ac433-dual-band-wireless-travel-router)

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KUB48KW) $104.99

- This unit is USB Powerable via 5V USB
- Supports IEEE802.11ac/n/a/g/b

Note: I would recommend reading the reviews on this model as there are a few things that it cannot do.  IE: 2.4 and 5G at the same time / lack of superior managmment interface